# Computer Monitor Fault

Tags: display

My monitor is 8 years old. Now when I turn my system on the power light on the monitor flashes for some time and then the monitor will kick in, and I get a picture and the button stops flashing. But, if I let it rest it does this all over again. Is this an old monitor or a computer problem? When I had it diagnosed they didn't find any problems in my computer parts. Can you help?

Comment: Try some basic troubleshooting: Attach another computer to the monitor and see if it does something similar. If it does, then we can determine that the initial computer may not be having issues and that it can be an issue related to the monitor

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your system has gone to sleep cutting off the display signal to your monitor. Nothing unusual here. If you provide your Operating System I will update my answer to include stopping your system going to sleep, although there really isn't anything to worry about.

I say this taking into account your monitor is 8 years old and likely similar to one I used to have. If, however, this behavior is somehow new do update your question taking this into account and an answer can be researched.

Comment: windows vista, but it only does this on start ups.

Comment: On startup only? Can you clarify here. When you boot your computer it will go through this process then repeat it while still in the bootup process?

Comment: I shut my sytem down at night.When I turn it on in the morning now the power button on the monitor  flashes for a minute or two before it starts to process.

Comment: Well a very simple check would be plug the monitor into another computer. If it does the same it's your monitor. If not it's your computer. Can you do this?

Comment: no,unfortunately I don't have another.I guess I'll wait to see if this one dies.

Comment: thank you for your help Mathew, I guess I can take it some where to check it on another Computer.

Comment: No problem. Let use know the result and we may be able to help further.